# "/usr/bin/node: No such file or directory" after `snap install node` and removing node apt-installed node

Tags: snap, nodejs

In Ubuntu 19.04, I did:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=13
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

But now if I do `node` or `nodejs`, I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a new shell and it'll work.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-bin-npm-no-such-file-or-directory-after-snap-remove-node-and-installing-node-via-apt/11981/4